How to summarize counts based on multiple conditions in R
I would like to summarize the number of each species that meet a certain condition for further analysis.
Here is an example of the data
df <- data.frame(Species = c("BRK","BRK","BRK","RGN","BRK","RGN"),
Length = c(4.2,4.4,5.3,1.6,5.9,8.2))

I would like to group by species and summarize the number of observations for each species that are greater than a certain length (say 4.5) and less than a certain length (<4.5).
I would like the resulting df to look something like:
df1 <- data.frame(Species = c("BRK","RGN"), Gtr_4.5 = c(2,1), Less_4.5 = c(2,1))

I can get the desired result by filtering and summarizing and then merging data but I know there is a way to do this using a combination of grouping and summarizing.
Here is an example of what I have tried and where I am stuck
summary <- df %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(Total_Captured = n())

I am having trouble figuring out how to summarize based on the conditions for length.

You can try
th <- 4.5
df %>%
  mutate(cond = str_c(c("Grt_", "Less_")[1 + (Length < th)], th)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = cond, values_from = Length, values_fn = length)

which gives
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Species Less_4.5 Grt_4.5
  <chr>      <int>   <int>
1 BRK            2       2
2 RGN            1       1


Also, you can use reframe
df %>%
  reframe(
    Gtr_4.5 = sum(Length > 4.5),
    Less_4.5 = sum(Length < 4.5),
    .by = Species
  )

or
df %>%
  summarise(
    Gtr_4.5 = sum(Length > 4.5),
    Less_4.5 = sum(Length < 4.5),
    .by = Species
  )

and you will obtain
  Species Gtr_4.5 Less_4.5
1     BRK       2        2
2     RGN       1        1


yet another approach:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  count(Species, Length <= 4.5) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = 2, values_from = 3) |>
  rename(le_4.5 = `TRUE`, gt_4.5 = `FALSE`)

for quick inspection with base R:
with(df, table(Species, Length <= 4.5))


Here is a way.
Transform Length into a categorical variable telling whether it's greater or less than the threshold you want, then aggregate with summarise.
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data.frame(Species = c("BRK","BRK","BRK","RGN","BRK","RGN"),
                 Length = c(4.2,4.4,5.3,1.6,5.9,8.2))

df %>%
  mutate(Length = ifelse(Length < 4.5, "< 4.5", "> 4.5")) %>%
  summarise(Total_Captured = n(), .by = c(Species, Length))
#>   Species Length Total_Captured
#> 1     BRK  < 4.5              2
#> 2     BRK  > 4.5              2
#> 3     RGN  < 4.5              1
#> 4     RGN  > 4.5              1

Created on 2024-12-30 with reprex v2.1.1
If you want the output in wide format:
df %>%
  mutate(Length = ifelse(Length < 4.5, "<4.5", ">4.5")) %>%
  summarise(Total_Captured = n(), .by = c(Species, Length)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    id_cols = Species, 
    names_from = Length, 
    names_glue = "Length{.name}",
    values_from = Total_Captured
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Species `Length<4.5` `Length>4.5`
#>   <chr>          <int>        <int>
#> 1 BRK                2            2
#> 2 RGN                1            1

Created on 2024-12-30 with reprex v2.1.1
